# How to delete row with a certain string in matlab

Tags: matlab

Another problem, that i would like to solved, if  i have string array:

```
A= [001   0
111    5
234    6
000    0
101    5]
```

a 5x2 array with zero string at column 2, i want to delete rows containing zero at column 2,

i tried using

```
A(A>0)=0
```

but it doesn't work

see desired output below:

```
 A= [111    5
    234    6
    101    5]
```

so as you can see 000, and 001 was deleted because they have zero in column 2, so how i would do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you talk about strings, I assume you have a *cell array*:

```
A = {'001'   '0'
     '111'   '5'
     '234'   '6'
     '000'   '0'
     '101'   '5'};
```

Then the desired output can be obtained with

```
A(strcmp(A(:,2),'0'),:) = [];
```